# How to analyze multi-threading overhead in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

My program looks like this:

```
Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

void work1(){
    while (true) {
        // do heavy work 1
        Object data;
        executor.execute(() -> work2(data));
    }
}

void work2(Object data){
    // do heavy work 2
}
```

I noticed that when `work2` becomes heavy it affects `work1` as well. It gets to the point when there is almost no gain in splitting the process into two threads.

What could be the reasons for this behavior and what tools do I have to find and analyze those problems?

Oh and here are my machine specs:

[image]

Comment: Well `executor` is *single threaded* so it make sense that heavy work might use more CPU that is available to  single thread.  The first tool to use here is a code review.  After that I'd try a thread analysis tool https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218228/how-to-use-threaddumpvisualizer-intellij-idea-plugin-to-analyze-java-thread-dump and also just looking at the OS load (`top` or Task Manager).

Comment: *"when work2 becomes heavy it affects work1 as well"* Can you give more details about this, in what way does it affect? What do work1 and work2 actually do?

Answer (score 1):

"while (true) {}" works fast but work2 is heavy and works slow. As a result, the number of tasks waiting for the single thread increases infinitely. So available core memory is exhausted and virtual memory is used, which is much slower. Standard thread pool is not designed to handle large number of tasks. A correct solution is as follows:

```
class WorkerThread extends Thread {
    ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10);
    public void run() {
        while true() {
           queue.take().run();
        }
     }
}

WorkerThread  workerThread = new WorkerThread();
workerThread.start();

void work1(){
    while (true) {
        Object data;
        // do heavy work
        workerThread.queue.put(() -> work2(data));
    }
 }
```

Using `ArrayBlockingQueue` keeps number of waiting tasks small.